# Verb for tax cut?

Tags: single-word-requests

My application will need to find a verb to fit:

> Regulator A and regulator B ________ a tax cut for XYZ products.

I want it to sound academic/professional. Best I could do was: "orchestrated" or "implemented" but I think the former comes off as a bit pretentious and the latter is too generic? Preference is a precise word for tax cuts.

Comment: Instituted, put in place, enacted, rammed through, voted for.  You need to be more specific on what kind of regulators, the process by which the tax cuts were put in place, whether you approve or disapprove of the cuts etc.

Comment: I'm with Jim in essence, yet I can surmise certain things however from your expressed appreciation for "orchestrated" other than it's 'pretentiousness" You're wanting equal parts creativity and forthouht of the plans efficacy and grace AS WELL as a canny and slightly machiavellian creativeness to the political moves to get in throug? (orchestrated is all positive on the essence of the plan,  a bit shadier on gaining support,.. so you want those colors to both.  "Conceived and sold"  is what I'd recommend as doing both with a business persons vocabulary (even if "sold" is a bit informal)

Comment: Some regulators may have the direct ability to set tax rates and fees in specific areas, others may have input to the legislative process (e.g. being consulted on a statutory basis), others may have to lobby politicians and work hard to get something enacted. In each case a different verb will apply.

Comment: Please take a look at the [detailed help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for this tag.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE - this seems more like a "writing advice" than a English Language Question ?

**Conceived and sold**
**Conceived and ushered through congressional approval**

*Regulator A and regulator B _**conceived**_**and **sold to congress**** a tax cut for XYZ products*

*Regulator A and regulator B _**conceived and ushered through congressional approval**___of a tax cut for XYZ products*  *

I'm with Jim in essence, yet I can surmise certain hopes I think you have from your expressed appreciation for "orchestrated" other than it's 'pretentiousness" You're wanting equal parts creativity and forethought of the plans efficacy and grace AS WELL as a canny and slightly machiavellian creativeness to the political moves to get it through? (orchestrated is all positive on the essence of the plan, a bit shadier on gaining support,.. so you want those colors to both. "Conceived and sold" is what I'd recommend as doing both with a business persons vocabulary (even if "sold" is a bit informal)

How sneaky you want the second party "maneuvering" or merely "explained" is less clear from your question but if you like "orchestrated" I think you want at least ... say a little "finesse" more than pure logical argument on the approval side